# Add image caption/title in Lightbox view on Blogger

Tags: blogger

When adding an image to a Blogger post, it's possible to add a caption, title and alt for the image. The caption is displayed under the image and the title is displayed on mouseover. But I can't see an option to display any of these when I view the image in full screen (or Lightbox) mode. This mode is available after clicking on an image. It's a kind of automatic gallery. It would be more useful if the gallery had an option to display the image title on mouseover.

Is there any way to achieve it?